How to check FIPS compliance for JavaScript libraries?
I've identified the crypto libraries(direct/indirect dependencies) being used in the application developed using the React Framework(JavaScript). I need to know if there's a way to identify if each of those individual libraries can be verified for FIPS 140-2 compliance?

React does not use relevant crypto. What dependencies in particular are you referring to?

For instance the use of crypto-js or the installed package having dependencies on modules such as crypto-browserify, crypto-random-string, etc.

react does not depend on crypto-js? Where are you seeing this?

https://www.virtru.com/press-release/virtru-announces-first-ever-fips-140-2-validated-javascript-cryptographic-module

FIPS 140-2 compliance is not a self assessed compliance , rather it is an elaborate and effort intensive process where the library / product or solution undergoes a series of test and validations around the various requirements of FIPS 140-2 certification.
Based on my knowledge If you are looking for a FIPS 140-2 compliant JavaScript Cryptographic Library, Virtru is the only option available. So any other library that you may be referring to is not FIPS compliant.
